# Upgrade to 22.02 changed /media/me/drive to /media/me/drive1

Tags: upgrade

I have a few apps (like Dropbox) that have a configuration file on /media/me/drive and now they won't start because they can't find the configuration file which is now on /media/me/drive1
I tried to use mv to restore the original name but it fails because "resource is in use".
Suggestions?

Comment: uninstall `Dropbox` then reinstall `Dropbox` from ubuntu software on 22.04 it has a different client anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the local folder location for Dropbox? It installs to ~ which is too small so I want it to install to its old location which is now on /media/me/drive1

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to specify the local folder location for Dropbox?

Absolutely. First go to the `Dropbox` icon in the system tray and right click `Preferences` and select `Sync`

From there you can `Choose the Dropbox Folder Location on this PC` and click `move`.

[image]

Comment: Fails with message that files are in use and cannot be moved.

Comment: a couple of things to try then. Are you trying to use an external drive as the DB location (if so, that might not work). Have you rebooted the PC? (hat should close any active files). Log out of DB (quit from drop down menu) and restart it. Back up files to another volume (for safety) then remove the DB app from ubuntu and reinstall (shouldn't remove files from DB itself).

Comment: That sounds promising. I only thought about that last night -- that the existence of the folder is confusing something. Will try later today when I have more time/energy.